# how to print something in the terminal for limited rime

Tags: python

I want to print random number in the terminal for just a few second

```
number = 10
print(number)
```

but I can't delete it after its display in terminal. is there any way to hide number after it show in terminal?

Comment: `os.system('cls')` if on Windows, `os.system('clear')` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go back to the beginning of the line with `\r` and `flush=True`, then overwrite the content of the line.

```
import time
print("secret message", end="\r", flush=True)
time.sleep(3)
print(" " * 20)
```

For more complex behaviour, including clearing more that just the current line, you should check out [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).